# define color palette from excel

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I would like to define a custom palette from an array of colors (rgb/hsv whatever etc). I can save the array in excel if needed. How can I go about this?

**EDIT**

say i built a swatch file like this, i would like to color these squares according to an array of rgb values I have already (see second picture). So far I can only do it by hand manually.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Copy - Paste? You need to define better your needs and workflow.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you are having trouble

Comment: thanks for the comments, see edit

Comment: Via a popular web search engine... the [*first* result](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/importing-color-to-swatch-library-from-text-file/td-p/2658071/page/2?page=1) answers this question over at the Adobe forums.

Comment: smh. thank you, i kept searching 'generate/make' but if i put 'import' would have gotten those results

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Scott, its very apparent here

https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/importing-color-to-swatch-library-from-text-file/td-p/2658071/page/2?page=1